# What approaches are there to show validation messages that originate in the Business Layer to appear in a contextual area in the Presentation Layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, design-patterns

In my presentation layer when a user wants to make a change the mvc framework maps their request to a ViewModel.  Then I map that viewmodel to a DTO and pass that DTO to my business layer.  I run validations against that DTO and then when validation errors occur I throw a ValidationException.  My presentation layer catches this ValidationException and will show these validation messages in a summary view at the top or bottom of the view.  I would rather instead show these validation messages next to the controls in which they are referring too, so, the user has a better feedback on what needs to be fixed.

My attempts at solving this problem were to attribute my ViewModel properties with a custom attribute that allowed me to Map validation messages that originated from the DTO to properties on my viewmodel.
So, the business layer would create validation messages like so:

```
if (personDto.FirstName == "Evan") {
  validationMessages.add("FirstName", "You cannot be Evan");
}
```

My viewmodel would have attributes like so:

```
public class PersonViewModel {
   [HandlesValidation("FirstName")]
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

This way I could catch the validation messages in the presentation layer and know where to map them in the View.

The only problem with this way is that I would have to create unique string constants for all my possible validation messages in the Business Layer and also my viewmodels would have to all be attributed appropriately.

I have searched around and couldn't find any solutions to this problem. It seems most everybody just uses the global validation summary for their business layer validation messages or rely on viewmodel validation.  I have yet to see any solutions detailing my particular problem.

Has anyone else come up with any elegant solutions to this problem?

Comment: Your problem is that the DAL is not the place for validation. It should be assumed that anything that reaches this point is valid. Validation happens at the presentation layer. Put your validation rules on your view models.

Comment: @ChrisPratt the counter argument to that is if you have multiple presentation layers/consumers, then you have to duplicate your validation (or create yet another layer between your presentation layers and DAL/business for validation). On the level, I'd still go with your suggestion though.

Comment: The actual entity should only require validation necessary for the database, i.e. if a field is NOT NULL, the corresponding property should be required. But that level of validation is *very* minimal. Most of it is handled implicitly (a `DateTime` is implicitly required, while `DateTime?` is allowed to be `NULL`). Other forms of validation (this text should be a phone number, etc.) is inherently presentation layer logic (and should be -- your database needn't and shouldn't give a flying flip). If you need to share that validation logic, then you can create a layer for that.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of agree with @Chris Pratt's comment, but also sort of disagree with it. I believe validation rules represent business knowledge, and therefore, do belong in the business layer.

However, allowing all presentation layer input go up to the business layer only to come back as an exception is not efficient. You should still pre-validate your viewmodels before sending them up to the business layer, to prevent avoidable exceptions from churning through the stack.

One elegant way to do this is by having your business layer DTO's double as your viewmodels. However that's not always possible, or even desirable. If you are using FluentValidation.NET for validation in your business layer though, there are some alternatives. If you wire up FV.NET to your MVC project as well, you could execute the same validation rules against your viewmodel first. For example:

```
public class SomeBusinessCommand
{
    public string PropertyX { get; set; }
}

public class SomeBusinessValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeBusinessCommand>
{
    public SomeBusinessValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Property1).NotEmpty().MustMeetSomeBusinessRequirement();
    }
}

public class SomeViewModel // assume this maps to SomeBusinessCommand
{
    public string PropertyX { get; set; }
}

public class SomeViewValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeViewModel>
{
    public SomeViewValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Property1).NotEmpty().MustMeetSomeBusinessRequirement();
    }
}
```

Now I know you are going to look at this and say it is not dry. That is sort of true. Like I said, this can be made completely dry if you use your business DTO's as your viewmodels. However even with this approach, we are achieving some levels of reuse. For example, both validators can use the same resources.resx file to get the validation messages. Also, the `MustMeetSomeBusinessRequirement` validation lives in your business layer, but is reused by both the business and presentation layers.

When FV.NET is plugged into MVC, it will preserve the property names for `ModelState` and you can display the validation messages next to their corresponding input fields. This is probably not the answer you were looking for, but I think at least the idea of pre-validating before you send bare input to the business layer is good advice.